# Two URLs for a website one with SSL

Tags: windows, iis, iis-7, ssl

I have a website in IIS7. It has 3 URLs.

www.mydomain.com
mydomain.com
secure.mydomain.com

secure.mydomain.com should be run with an SSL certificate.. Hitting http://secure.mydomain.com should hit the https site. Hitting any of the two other addresses with https should take you to http version's ten URL.

is it possible to set his up in IIS 7?

Answer (score 2):

Yep. Use redirects:

1. https://www.mydomain.com -> www.mydomain.com
2. https://mydomain.com -> mydomain.com
3. http://secure.mydomain.com -> https://secure.mydomain.com

How-To: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732930(WS.10).aspx

Comment: I recommend using the "Permanent Redirect" option which issues an HTTP 301 "Permanent Redirect" Response code vs the HTTP 302 "Temporary Redirect" Response code.  This is better for SEO purposes... Google likes permanent redirects more than temporary redirects.